# Double push view when tap more times - Sencha Touch

Tags: sencha-touch-2

I need to help a big problem.
When i get event "tap" Ext.button, with follow code:

```
var nav = button.up("MainNav");
if (!this.waitingView) {
     this.waitingView = {xtype: "WaitingShowView"};
}
nav.push(this.waitingView);
```

My Navigation pushed double same View "WaitingView".
Also, I have to back twice to go back root view.
How do i do? Thanks.

Comment: hi. did u find solution for this?

Comment: Sorry! I until find the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

is it firing the 'tap' event twice? or just executing two nav.push(this.waitingView) ?

Also, try executing it from the button handler instead of catching the tap event:

** Update:

```
{
    xtype: 'button',
    text: 'myButton',
    handler: function() {
        this.up("MainNav").push({
            xtype: 'WaitingShowView'
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: In function Button "Tap". I have a ajax request. When requesting success, i will push a new view. I added Ext.Viewport.setMask(...)
But, when pushing process i tap this button again, it still fire "tap" function. ==> So, I had 2 events push a same view.

Answer (score 0):

try this one..

```
 yourTasksAction:function(){
    if(this.delayedTask == null){
        //setup a delayed task that is called IF double click is not later detected
        this.delayedTask = new Ext.util.DelayedTask(
            function(){
                 /*
                   Put your button action code here
                */
                this.delayedTask = null;
            }, this);
        this.delayedTask.delay(300);
    }
},
```